# UI element with onTapGesture function does not work Swift

Tags: swift, iphone, swiftui

I use a systemImage, with a onTapGesture function attached to it, to switch a boolean Variable to true. When that boolean variable is true, the view is changed. I positioned that systemImage at the top left part of the screen, using position(x:,y:) function. However, onTapGesture does not work when the value for "y" is bellow 100.

The code:

```
import SwiftUI
import FirebaseFirestoreSwift
import Firebase

struct ChatView: View {
    
  
    @Environment(\.presentationMode) var presentationMode
    @StateObject var homeData:HomeModel
    @State var queryView:Bool = false
   
    @EnvironmentObject var model:ContentModel
    var user = Auth.auth().currentUser
    let db = Firestore.firestore()
    //If it is the first time when user scrolls
    @State var scrolled = false
 //   @GestureState var isLongPressed = false
    
    var body: some View {
     
        if queryView == false {
        
            
                VStack(spacing: 0) {
                  
                    Text("\(homeData.query) Global Chat").foregroundColor(Color(#colorLiteral(red: 0.5951357484, green: 0.5694860816, blue: 1, alpha: 1))).font(.title3).padding(.top, 30)
                    Text("Welcome \(model.firstName) \(model.secondName) !").foregroundColor(Color(#colorLiteral(red: 0.5951357484, green: 0.5694860816, blue: 1, alpha: 1))).font(.callout)
                  
                    Image(systemName: "arrow.backward.square")
                        .position(x: 30, y: 0)
                        .foregroundColor(Color(#colorLiteral(red: 0.5951357484, green: 0.5694860816, blue: 1, alpha: 1)))
                        .font(.system(size: 30, weight: .regular))
                        .onTapGesture {
                            withAnimation(.easeOut) {
                                queryView = true
                            }
                            print("TAPPED")
                        }
                
                    ScrollViewReader { reader in
                        
                        ScrollView{
                         

                            VStack(spacing: 15) {
                                ForEach(homeData.msgs) { msg in
                                    
                                    ChatRow(chatData: msg, firstName: model.firstName, secondName: model.secondName).onAppear(){
                                        
                                        if msg.id == self.homeData.msgs.last!.id && !scrolled {
                                            
                                            reader.scrollTo(homeData.msgs.last!.id, anchor: .bottom)
                                            scrolled = true
                                            
                                        }
                                        //  print(model.firstName)
                                        // print(model.secondName)
                                    }
                                    
                                }.onChange(of: homeData.msgs) { value in
                                    
                                    reader.scrollTo(homeData.msgs.last!.id, anchor: .bottom)
                                    
                                }
                                
                            }
                            
                        }.padding(.vertical)
                      
                    }.frame(width: UIScreen.main.bounds.size.width, height: UIScreen.main.bounds.size.height - 135)
                    
                    HStack(spacing:15) {
                        TextField("Enter message", text: $homeData.txt)
                            .padding(.horizontal)
                        //Fixed height for animation...
                            .frame(height: 45)
                            .foregroundColor(Color(.black))
                            .background(Color(#colorLiteral(red: 0.5951357484, green: 0.5694860816, blue: 1, alpha: 1)).opacity(1.0))
                            .clipShape(Capsule())
                        if homeData.txt != "" {
                            Button {
                                homeData.writeAllMessages()
                            } label: {
                                Image(systemName: "paperplane.fill")
                                    .font(.system(size: 22))
                                    .foregroundColor(.white)
                                    .frame(width: 45, height: 45)
                                    .background(Color(#colorLiteral(red: 0.5951357484, green: 0.5694860816, blue: 1, alpha: 1)))
                                    .clipShape(Circle())
                            }
                            
                        }
                    }.animation(.default)
                        .padding()
                    Spacer().frame(height: 100)
               }.background(Color(.black).scaledToFill().frame(width: UIScreen.main.bounds.size.width, height: UIScreen.main.bounds.size.height).ignoresSafeArea())
                .navigationBarBackButtonHidden(true)

      
    } else {
        QueryView(query: homeData.query)
    }
    }
}
```

What shall I do in order to make that TapGesture work anywhere on the screen?
To provide more info,I use the systemImage with that tapgesture function because when I use the NavigationLink back button the transition to its parent view is too slow and laggy.

Comment: Its likely because there is another view on top of your image. `ChatView` is a subview of some other view, but you're trying to position the system image outside the frame of `ChatView`. Use the View Hierarchy debugger to get an understanding of your layout.

Comment: I see a lot of hardcoded values, there is likely a lot of trying to fight SwiftUI going on.

Comment: Thank you! I solved the issue with .navigationBarHidden(true) and using the View Hierarchy debugger.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's probably because the `NavigationBar` is still at the top of your View even though the Back button is hidden.

Try adding `.navigationBarHidden(true)` instead of  `.navigationBarBackButtonHidden(true)`.